# input element of type range leaks in UIWebView

Tags: memory-leaks, uiwebview, webkit, app-store, html-input

I was about to submit my app for review when I discovered that the input element of type range in my UIWebView leaks 12 bytes when added to the document. There are no subsequent leaks; not even when the slider is used.

I would be grateful for any advice as to how to proceed with my submission. Should I be worried at all about 12 bytes? Should I find a way around this, say, by not using this element at all? Or, should I make a note of the leak to the reviewers (under Review Notes rubric)?

The leak can be replicated with a minimal UIWebView application:

```
#import "TjaViewController.h"

@interface TjaViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end

@implementation TjaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<input type='range'>" baseURL:nil];
}

@end
```

Profiling the app with Instruments yields a single leak with the following properties:

Category: Malloc 12 Bytes 
Retain Count: 1 
Responsible Library: JavaScriptCore 
Responsible Caller: WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long)

Stack trance:

```
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start
30 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
29 WebCore RunWebThread(void*)
28 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
27 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
26 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
25 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
24 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
23 WebCore HandleRunSource
22 WebCore ___ZN7WebCoreL26applicationDidBecomeActiveEP22__CFNotificationCenterPvPK10__CFStringPKvPK14__CFDictionary_block_invoke
21 WebCore WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal()
20 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::handleSubstituteDataLoadNow(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::DocumentLoader>*)
19 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::responseReceived(WebCore::CachedResource*, WebCore::ResourceResponse const&)
18 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::continueAfterContentPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction)
17 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::dataReceived(WebCore::CachedResource*, char const*, int)
16 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int)
15 WebKit WebFrameLoaderClient::committedLoad(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, char const*, int)
14 WebKit -[WebDataSource(WebInternal) _receivedData:]
13 WebKit -[WebHTMLRepresentation receivedData:withDataSource:]
12 WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitData(char const*, unsigned long)
11 WebCore WebCore::DecodedDataDocumentParser::appendBytes(WebCore::DocumentWriter*, char const*, unsigned long)
10 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::append(WTF::PassRefPtr<WTF::StringImpl>)
9 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode)
8 WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::constructTreeFromHTMLToken(WebCore::HTMLToken&)
7 WebCore WebCore::HTMLConstructionSite::executeQueuedTasks()
6 WebCore WebCore::executeTask(WebCore::HTMLConstructionSiteTask&)
5 WebCore WebCore::insert(WebCore::HTMLConstructionSiteTask&, bool)
4 WebCore WebCore::HTMLInputElement::attach(WebCore::Node::AttachContext const&)
3 WebCore WebCore::FeatureObserver::didObserve(WebCore::FeatureObserver::Feature)
2 JavaScriptCore WTF::BitVector::resizeOutOfLine(unsigned long)
1 JavaScriptCore WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long)
0 JavaScriptCore WTF::MallocHook::recordAllocation(void*, unsigned long)
```

Comment: I think it's some bug in webkit core

Comment: I tried to use loadRequest to obtain a webpage and got a same leak WebCore::FeatureObserver::observe(WebCore::Document*, WebCore::FeatureObserver::Feature)
WebCore::FeatureObserver::didObserve(WebCore::FeatureObserver::Feature)
WTF::BitVector::resizeOutOfLine(unsigned long)
WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long)
WTF::MallocHook::recordAllocation(void*, unsigned long)

Comment: Thank you @buaacss for confirming the leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out

Seems it's a leak in libWTF

and here is the original code from https://github.com/leolannenmaki/JavaScriptCore-iOS

```
void BitVector::resizeOutOfLine(size_t numBits)
{
    ASSERT(numBits > maxInlineBits());
    OutOfLineBits* newOutOfLineBits = OutOfLineBits::create(numBits);
    size_t newNumWords = newOutOfLineBits->numWords();
    if (isInline()) {
    // Make sure that all of the bits are zero in case we do a no-op resize.
        *newOutOfLineBits->bits() = m_bitsOrPointer & ~(static_cast<uintptr_t>(1) << maxInlineBits());
        memset(newOutOfLineBits->bits() + 1, 0, (newNumWords - 1) * sizeof(void*));
    } else {
        if (numBits > size()) {
            size_t oldNumWords = outOfLineBits()->numWords();
            memcpy(newOutOfLineBits->bits(), outOfLineBits()->bits(), oldNumWords * sizeof(void*));
            memset(newOutOfLineBits->bits() + oldNumWords, 0, (newNumWords - oldNumWords) * sizeof(void*));
        } else
            memcpy(newOutOfLineBits->bits(), outOfLineBits()->bits(), newOutOfLineBits->numWords() * sizeof(void*));
        OutOfLineBits::destroy(outOfLineBits());
    }
    m_bitsOrPointer = bitwise_cast<uintptr_t>(newOutOfLineBits) >> 1;
}
```

And it's obviously the newOutOfLineBits is not destroied when code goes isInline()

I tried to replace the system JavascriptCore.framework

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework

but failed, the system framework is compiled from dynamic library

as far as I know, apple forbids compile dynamic library for iOS...

so I think the only way is to report this leak to Apple...

Comment: Thanks @buaacss! I submitted the bug report.

Comment: We think we also have some leaks that according to Instruments come from WTF::FastMalloc. However for us it is from loading an image. Could you point me to the bug you submitted to Apple?

Comment: Bug report 17808677 "<input> element of type range leaks in UIWebView"